# return from function inside the Using operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is the pseudo-code below ok? 
I just want to know if it always better to have return outside the DataContext instead.

```
public object returnObjectFromDB () { 
   using(var mydatacontext = new Mydatacontext()) 
   { 
       return someobject; 
   }    
}
```

Comment: That's good coding style, I've always found it very expressive and it reduces redundant code that you have with other styles.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this will still execute the `finally` clause of the using statement, i.e. Disposing your context.

A quick way to test this would be to throw an exception inside of the Dispose method you are using.

There is not a strong convention one way or the other, but either way is supported. I personally don't do this often because I feel it affects readability slightly but that is just my personal opinion. Sometimes I will return early when I reach a condition which would invalidate the rest of the work with the data context.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is

> Will a return from inside a using statement still properly dispose of `mydatacontext`?

Then the answer is indeed yes.  The `using` block is implemented as a `try / finally` and hence it's protects the dispose against both exceptions and explicit returns.

But if your question is

> Is it safe to return from inside a using statement?

That requires a bit more knowledge of the situation.  If `someobject` is independent of the value being disposed then yes this is safe.  However if `someobject` is dependent upon the value then you can get into trouble because you may end up holding onto a disposed value.  For example if the code looked like this

```
return new SomeObject(mydatacontext);
```

This code would properly dispose of `mydatacontext` and then return a value which holds a reference to that disposed value.  Probably not safe